# Golang Serverless Offline

Tags: go, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework, serverless

I'm new to the serverless framework and I have some questions: 
I have an APIGateway with Go Lang developed on the Serverless framework and I am trying to get serverless offline to work.
I already installed the serverless-offline plugin and when I run the sls offline start command everything goes as expected.

When I run the "Get" route in the browser, I am getting the following error:

[image]

My functions config in serverless.yml

```
functions:
      getOrders:
        # The handler property points to the file and module containing the code you want to run in your function.
        handler: cmd/api/getOrders
        memorySize: 128 # Memory Size available to function while running
        description: Get all orders and convert them.
        events:
          - http:
              path: orders
              method: get
```

My handler:

```golang
func getAllOrders(ctx context.Context, request events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {

        orders := services.GetAllOrders()

        // Success HTTP response
        body, _ := json.Marshal(&models.ListOrdersResponse{
            Orders: orders,
        })

        return events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
            Body:       string(body),
            StatusCode: 200,
        }, nil
    }

    func main() {
        lambda.Start(getAllOrders)
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://github.com/dherault/serverless-offline/issues/775
As stated here in this link, this is already a known issue of the plugin that resulted in a Go Lang incompatibility and for this reason Go Lang was taken from the Readme.

Comment: Yea, too bad too :-(